# angularJS print directive losing 2 way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing, angularjs-directive

I have a print directive in a SPA that seems to lose its 2 way data binding after the first print function is ran. I am sure it has something to do with the cloning and appending of the element.

The Directive is as follows:

```
agency.directive("pasPrint", ['AgentModel','Dev', 
function(agentModel, dev) {
var printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
function printElement(elem) {
    // clones the element you want to print
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    if (!printSection) {
        printSection = document.createElement("div");
        printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild(printSection);
    } else {
        printSection.innerHTML = "";
    }
    printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
        $scope.printModel = {};
        $scope.today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
        $element.on("click", function () {
            var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(attrs.printElementId);
            if (elemToPrint) {
                printElement(elemToPrint);
                window.print();
            }
        });
    },
    controller: ["$scope","$element", "AgentModel", function($scope, $element, agentModel) {
        $scope.agentModel = agentModel;
    }]
};
}]);
```

the model that is used in the entire module here is the agentModel.singleAgent which of course represents a single agent. this directive simply prints a cover sheet for an agents hard copy record. the first time we pull up an agents record the cover sheet prints correctly. when we load another agent the print preview show's the correctly updated agent information. in the agentModel.singleAgent 2 way binding (the same values being used in the printSection that gets printed. However the second print attempt also prints the first agent information and so does any other attempt to print any other agents, they all print the first agents data, even thought the singleAgent model has been updated properly.

the html from the print preview is below:

```
<div class="modal-header ng-scope">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-ng- click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true"> &times; </span></button>
  <h3 class="modal-title ng-binding"> Edit &amp; Print Cover Sheet </h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">            
   <form class="inline-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="PRINT_DESC">File Description:   </label>
        <input class="input-medium" type="text" id="PRINT_DESC" name="PRINT_DESC" data-ng-model="printModel.PRINT_DESC" />
    </div>
</form>
<div id="printPreview">
    <table class="table table-cell-nowrap table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><strong>Type: <em>{{printModel.PRINT_DESC}}</em></strong></th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px #dadada dotted"><div class="clearfix pull-right"><strong>{{agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_NUMBER}}</strong></div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Agent Name: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_LNAME }}, {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_FNAME }} </strong></td>
                <td><strong>Agent #: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_NUMBER }}</strong></td>
                <td><strong>UID: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_UID }}</strong></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4">Printed On: {{ today }} </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="printSection" class="col-md-12"><!-- place nothing in here except what should be printed. by default the content in the print section IS hidden -->        
    <table class="table table-cell-nowrap table-responsive printCoverFontSize">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><strong>Type: <em>{{printModel.PRINT_DESC}}</em></strong></th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px #dadada dotted"><div class="clearfix pull-right"><strong>{{agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_NUMBER}}</strong></div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Agent Name: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_LNAME }}, {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_FNAME }} </strong></td>
                <td><strong>Agent #: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_NUMBER }}</strong></td>
                <td><strong>UID: {{ agentModel.singleAgent.AGENT_UID }}</strong></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4">Printed On: {{ today }} </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="pull-left">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" data-pas-print data-print-element-id="printSection"><i class="fa fa-print fa-lg"></i> Print </button>
   </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng- click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
 </div>
```

the printModel model simply takes the value from the text box and includes it to be printed, just a descriptive term.
I am at a loss as to why this is not working. I did just piece this together from other scripts I found online to work with our application. I am a bit of an angular Newb and I really appreciate any help I can get so thank you in advance. please if you need more information feel free to ask. If I had to guess I would say it has something to do with cloning and the emptying of the element if I had to guess, but I am at a loss as to how to fix it. HELP please.

Comment: your basic problem is you aren't working entirely with your data model because you are manually manipulating the dom and not letting angular do it for you. Work with your data model only

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for being so helpful, my what an uncanny grasp of the obvious you have. Think you could help? Maybe a nudge in the right direction? newb here.